# Download View and show popup message

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How to show message in showDialog();

I want when freshDownloadView is finished show showDialog.
My code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private FreshDownloadView freshDownloadView;
private Button btDownloaded;
private TextView btReset;
private TextView btDownloadError;
private final int FLAG_SHOW_OK = 10;
private final int FLAG_SHOW_ERROR = 11;

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

        int progress = (int) msg.obj;
        freshDownloadView.upDateProgress(progress);

        switch (msg.what) {

            case FLAG_SHOW_OK:


               break;

            case FLAG_SHOW_ERROR:
               freshDownloadView.showDownloadError();
              break;
        }
    }
};

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    freshDownloadView = (FreshDownloadView) findViewById(R.id.pitt);
    btDownloaded = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_downloaded);
    btReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_reset);
    btDownloadError = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_download_error);
    btDownloaded.setOnClickListener(this);
   btReset.setOnClickListener(this);
    btDownloadError.setOnClickListener(this);

}
```

this is button freshDownload

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bt_downloaded:
            if (freshDownloadView.using()) return;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(50);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        message.obj = i;
                        handler.sendMessage(message);

                        showDialog();
                    }

                }

            }).start();

            break;

        case R.id.bt_reset:
            freshDownloadView.reset();
            break;
        case R.id.bt_download_error:
            if (freshDownloadView.using()) return;
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for (int i = 0; i <= 30; i++) {
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        Message message = Message.obtain();
                        if (i == 30) {
                            message.what = FLAG_SHOW_ERROR;
                        }
                        message.obj = i;
                        handler.sendMessage(message);
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            break;
    }
}


public void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title)
            .setMessage(R.string.download_app)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
    builder.create().show();
}

protected void onPause() {
    //  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    //  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
    //  WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `AsyncTask` for this. You can initiate the download in the `doInBackground` method and show the alert dialog (as needed) in the `onPostExecute` method. This will also free you from using `Thread.sleep(100)` which isn't a good practice on Android.

However, if you still prefer to use the `FreshDownloadView` please update your question with the code for `FreshDownloadView` and we can suggest something.